# Dataflow BigQueryBatchFileLoads cant find project ID with DirectRunner

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm trying to locally debug a Dataflow job which batch uploads to BigQuery but when running locally using the DirectRunning BigQueryBatchFileLoads spits out

```
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Project id is missing",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Project id is missing",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
```

I've tried hard coding the project id`options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions).project = PROJECT_ID`  
And using cli flags `python mycode.py --dataset mydataset --project myprojectid`
but no luck.

From what I can gather, BigQueryBatchFileLoads is getting the project ID from a runtime value provider and I've attempted to debug the values in the value provider in a DoFn but could not resolve any values.

I'm new to Dataflow / ApacheBeam so I'm hoping the answer is something benign as this must be a very common use case.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to set the project id in the beam config if your environment is set up properly. Maybe you need to run `gcloud config set project my-project`.

Comment: My gcloud is correctly configured

Comment: make sure `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable is set. This issue isn't related to your beam pipeline, something in your environment isn't set correctly.

Comment: Have you tried --project=<project> --dataset=<dataset> assuming your using     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() from the examples along with pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using WriteToBigQuery - have you tried passing a table name that includes the project name?

Also, what version of Beam are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue recently as well with DirectRunner. Spent much time troubleshooting and found some workarounds!

In your WriteToBigQuery Step,

- Workaround 1 (Will work with templating)

  Indicate the project directly either using the `project=[PROJECT]` parameter or `table=[PROJECT]:[DATASET].[TABLE]` parameter.
- Workaround 2 (Will not work when templating)

  If you indicated the table parameter without the project i.e. `table=[DATASET].[TABLE]` and parsed `--project [PROJECT]` argument when you run the code in CLI, use the following syntax `table="{}".format("[DATASET].[TABLE]")`. I'm not sure why this works, but I'm guessing it's a bug with Apache Beam.

Tested on 2.30.0.

Hope it helps!